# iphone - store NSTimeInterval on a coredata

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have an entry on a core data entity that represents a NSTimeInterval.

First question: How do I represent this entity on the dababase model? Double? Float?

Then, when I store it, is it fine to create an object like

```
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:myTimeInterval];

or

[NSNumber numberWithDouble:myTimeInterval];
```

or should I convert everything to string and store it like that?

thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

NSTimeInterval is a double.  Store it with the latter line.  There's no need to store it as an NSString.

Comment: thanks! Just out of curiosity, how do you know it is a double?

Comment: If you Command-Double-Click on NSTimeInterval in XCode, it will take you to the header file where NSTimeInterval is typedef from double.

Comment: For all it's worth, this is documented here: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW69