# Storing time (hours:minutes) in CoreData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

How should I properly store hour:minute data of my entity in CoreData?
In .NET I could use TimeSpan class, how about objective C?
The options I see:
1)use CoreData Date type (NSDate?) and ignore every component except for hour and minute
2)use custom type based on string stored as "HH:MM"
3)store two integers

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the NSTimeInterval class, much like the TimeSpan .NET class.

Comment: I do agree with @Simeon below that if you're going to store a lot of these then I would store some integers instead, but if you are only storing a few records, the NSTimeInterval is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

`NSTimeInterval` is the correspondant data type: [iphone - store NSTimeInterval on a coredata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527893/iphone-store-nstimeinterval-on-a-coredata)

However, if your data is large, I would suggest the optimization to store two integers instead. If you decide to later on also store seconds, the `NSTimeInterval` solution is a more flexible one.